# Why doesn't doesn't this jQuery remove function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn about dynamic generation of html using jQuery. I have been working on the following forked code.

http://jsfiddle.net/plusxultra/4r22b/5/

```
$(function () {
    var myDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
        $('<label for="p_scents"><input type="text" id="c_name" size="20" name="c_name_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_name" /><input type="text" id="c_acc" size="20" name="c_acc_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_acc" /><input type="text" id="c_desc" size="20" name="c_desc_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_desc" /></label><a href="#" id="removeButton">Remove</a><br>').appendTo(myDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#removeButton').live('click', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I was able to dynamically create additional inputs, which serves my purpose, but for some reason the remove functionality does not work. I am sure I am doing something wrong, I have tried to debug for a while no to no avail. Is anyone able to solve this?

p.s. using jquery-1.6.4.min.js

Comment: use .length instead of .size() it is deprecated and function overhead

Comment: use .on as .live is deprecated too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4r22b/6/)

The problem is that you are not adding `<p>` elements.

Just use

```
$('<p><label for="p_scents"><input type="text" id="c_name" size="20" name="c_name_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_name" /><input type="text" id="c_acc" size="20" name="c_acc_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_acc" /><input type="text" id="c_desc" size="20" name="c_desc_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_desc" /></label><a href="#" id="removeButton">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(myDiv);
```

Note the `<p>` at the beginning and `</p>` at the end.

Offtopic: why are you using those labels? Labels should be used to relate some content to an input, but you are using them to relate some inputs to a div.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) refers to the button, I don't think that's your target.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way how to do it:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r22b/10/)

**Code**

```
    $(function () {
        var myDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

//here you will have html which will be added every time the add button is clicked
//place it inside the div so it will be easier to find which input to remove
    var newInput='<div>'+myDiv.html()+ '<a href="#" id="removeButton">Remove</a>'+'</div>';
        $('#addScnt').on('click', function () {
            $(newInput).appendTo(myDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
        });

        $('#removeButton').on('click', function () {
//removing only the closest div
            $(this).closest('div').remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4r22b/9/

change the id property of the link to class because id are suppose to be unique and also place the `<p>` which you are looking for.

```
<a href="#" class="removeButton">Remove</a>

$('.removeButton').live('click', function () {

        $(this).parents('p').remove();

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your original code.  Most notably you are not incrementing the `id` attribute which will cause issues because those should be unique.  If you increment the `id` attributes then you need to change your live statement.  Finally the remove is not working because you are missing the

tags in the appendTo function.  Here is the working and updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/VVnMu/3/